# Show That $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ And $\frac{x^2}{A^2} - \frac{y^2}{B^2} = 1$ Are Orthogonal Trajectories

Tags: calculus, inequality

Show that the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ and the hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{A^2} - \frac{y^2}{B^2} = 1$ are orthogonal trajectories if $A^2< a^2$ and $a^2-b^2 = A^2+B^2$.

**What I've managed so far:**

**1)** $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 \Rightarrow y' = -\frac{xb^2}{ya^2}$

**2)** $\frac{x^2}{A^2} - \frac{y^2}{B^2} = 1 \Rightarrow y' = \frac{xB^2}{yA^2}$

**3)** I want to show the product of the derivatives are equal to $-1$, $(-\frac{xb^2}{ya^2})(\frac{xB^2}{yA^2})= -\frac{b^2B^2}{a^2A^2}\frac{x^2}{y^2}$

Now I'm stuck, I can't find a way to relate $A^2< a^2$ and $a^2-b^2 = A^2+B^2$ to **1)**, **2)**  or **3)**.

Comment: Solve for $x^2,y^2$ and put their values in $(3)$

Comment: I could be wrong, but don't you just find  $\nabla F (x, y)$, and $\nabla $ $ G (x, y) $. And show their dot product is zero all the time? Where $ F (x, y)=(\frac{x^2}{a^2})+(\frac {y^2}{b^2})=1$, and $G (x, y)=(\frac {x^2}{a^2})-(\frac {y^2}{b^2})=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Solving $x^2,y^2$, you will obtain
$$x^2=\frac{a^2A^2(b^2+B^2)}{A^2b^2+a^2B^2},y^2=\frac{(a^2-A^2)b^2B^2}{A^2b^2+a^2B^2}$$
(in this situation, $a^2>A^2$ is required) and then check if
$$ -\frac{b^2B^2}{a^2A^2}\frac{x^2}{y^2}=-1? $$
by using the given condition.

Comment: Additionally, the $a^2 > A^2$ is necessary for $y^2$ to be a positive number. In other words if $a^2 < A^2$ there are no intersection points.

Comment: @AlexZorn, that's right.

Comment: That did it. I solved it using another method that seemed less tedious to me. I subtracted **(1)**-**(2)** and used the fact that $a^2 - b^2= A^2 + B^2$ to solve for $\frac{x^2}{y^2}$. Thanks for your assistance, I appreciate it.

Comment: You have one brace too many in your $y^2$ equation and the product of the derivatives should be equal to $-1$ instead of $1$. I tried to edit, but edits should be more than 6 characters.